# How to sync downloaded fonts over CC

Tags: creative-cloud, font-management

I'm currently studying graphic design and find I do a lot of work at home and then bring that work into class only to find I have to re-download all my fonts to work on my documents.

My teacher has told me that by simply logging into my Adobe CC account it will automatically sync whatever fonts I use on my personal home computer onto the school computer. However I have found this not to be the case.

I know you can download fonts from typekit and have them sync, but I want the fonts I've downloaded from dafont/fontsquirell etc to sync. Is this at all possible, and if so, could someone explain to me the process? Because simply signing in doesn't do it.

Comment: I don't have CC so I don't know for sure but AFAIK you can only sync fonts through typekit, I just had another quick look through the help files too and it seems that is the case. (I may be wrong though)

Comment: Inconvenient but sure way to have your favorite fonts is to carry the font files in a folder on portable media. In windows 10 if I drag font files into ControlPanel/FONTS they are available immediately in illustrator, word etc. I've never had a setting be retained on a school computer.

Answer (score 1):

Typekit lets you sync fonts in its library between systems that are signed in with the same account credentials. Unfortunately this doesn't allow you to sync fonts downloaded externally.

One app that *can* do this, however, is [**Rightfont**](http://rightfontapp.com/). It allows you to sync fonts – any fonts – across multiple computers using Dropbox or Google Drive, and lets you preview and use Typekit and Google Fonts. It's a great little app.

If you don't want to use Rightfont but do have a Dropbox account, you could simply create a 'Fonts' folder in Dropbox, save your fonts into it. This won't 'sync' the fonts, but it will mean they're accessible from wherever you are.

Comment: Hi @Permanoob, if an answer answers your question, please mark it as an answer by clicking the check mark below the upvote and downvote buttons. This way the answerer is rewarded and the system can file the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Font Sync](http://www.fontsync.xyz) to keep different companies up-to-date with whatever fonts I'm using. It runs through Dropbox or Google Drive.